# OR function in if (trim() == "") {}in PHP

Tags: php

OR function in `if (trim() == "") {}` in PHP?

tried this, not work:

```
if (trim($query) == "a" or "b") {$search= 'd'; }
```

I want if either a or b exist d goes to $search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn PHP the right way from [PHP Manual](http://php.net/). It should be:

```
if (trim($query) == "a" || trim($query) == "b") {
  $search= 'd';
}
```

Or you can use `in_array`:

```
if (in_array(trim($query), array('a', 'b'))) {
  $search = 'd';
}
```

If you wanna look for partial ones, then you can do:

```
if (strpos("a", trim($query)) > -1 || strpos("b", trim($query)) > -1) {
```

Comment: I would have use `in_array` with`true` as 3rd argument.

Comment: `$query = '1a'` or something alphanumeric!!

Comment: You mean partly match? Could you edit your code so it could work on partly match as well?

Comment: @SasanSmith What do you mean by partly match?

Comment: e.g: if instead a there be 1a still caz a exist the d goes to $search

Comment: @SasanSmith You can use `substr()`. Updating the answer.

Comment: your new code doesn't work for partly match but still works for exact match

Comment: @SasanSmith Change the parameters, like `if (strpos(trim($query), "a") > -1 || strpos(trim($query), "b") > -1) {` - Does this work?

Comment: @SasanSmith Happy! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

In your conditional, you must use the if statement 2x with `or` or `||` operator, like this:

```
if (trim($query) == "a" or trim($query) == "b") {$search= 'd'; }
```

You can also use this:

```
if (trim($query) == "a" || trim($query) == "b") {$search= 'd'; }
```

Of course, you can also use `in_array()` function in your statement:

```
if (in_array(trim($query), array('a', 'b'))) {
  $search = 'd';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( in_array( trim($query), array('a', 'b') ) ) {
  $search = 'd';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy

```
if (trim($query) == "a" or trim($query) == "b"){
   // Do somenthing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably should not use the `or` operator, since it has a very weird precedence. Use `||` instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Second, you need to compare the result of trim twice. `or` is a simple logical operator that evaluates boolean expressions and returns a bool, it won't magically make two comparisons happen.

```
$query = trim(query);
if ($query === 'a' || $query === 'b') { $search = 'd'; }
```